# DOM changes with alert

Tags: javascript, dom, alert

I have a `while` loop going with an `alert()` inside. Inside the `while` loop, I want to change the content of an element, in this case with a counter.

I have a snippet which shows the idea.

```js
var test = document.querySelector('div#test');
var limit = 5;
var counter = 0;
do {
  counter++;
  test.textContent = counter;
  console.log(counter)
  alert('waiting …');
} while (counter<limit);
```

```css
div#test {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

For testing purposes, I also include a `console.log()` but in the snippet it’s not working like a normal console.

I know that `alert()` is very disruptive, and blocks other activity. However, I find that somehow it prevents the element content from being changed, even though that statement is *before* the `alert()` in the loop. However, the `console.log()` statement is working, even though you can’t see it in the SO snippet. On a browser, such as Firefox and Safari, the `console.log()` prints the new value, but the element content stays unchanged until the end.

I also want the change the CSS style of the element, but I’ve left that off the sample. In any case it doesn’t work either.

I’m curious about what seems to be inconsistent behaviour. What is happening here, and is there a way to allow changes to the element to occur when there’s an `alert()` going on?

Comment: DOM changes are only processed after all javascript has finished running. To do what you want, you'll need to construct something that uses setTimeout or setInterval.

Comment: @PeterB I wasn’t aware of that. Are you able to give a reference for that?

Comment: I don't have a list of references ready but I think this answer explains it rather well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43508576/1220550

Comment: @PeterB, no, the DOM is processed synchronously. What happens is that `alert()` will also block the *rendering* part of the event loop. But the DOM is already updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is sync meaning you change the `counter` inside 1 JS task without allowing the browser to re-render the page. The rendering happens in the end of a JS task. To allow the browser to render you should split your logic into JS tasks. `setTimeout` and `requestAnimationFrame` create a new JS task for example.

We have a problem with Firefox though. Seems it optimizes the rendering and if several JS tasks are queued, it re-renders after all the queue is complete. So I've added 10ms delay to `setTimeout`. But `requestAnimationFrame` works fine in all browsers:

```js
var test = document.querySelector('div#test');

const wait = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10));

(async()=>{

  var limit = 5;
  var counter = 0;
  do {
    counter++;
    test.textContent = counter;
    console.log(counter);
    alert('waiting …');
    await wait();
  } while (counter<limit);

})();
```

```css
div#test {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

A simplified solution:

```js
var test = document.querySelector('div#test');

var limit = 5;
var counter = 0;

const count = () => {
    counter++;
    test.textContent = counter;
    console.log(counter);
    alert('waiting …');
    counter<limit && setTimeout(count, 10);
};
count();
```

```css
div#test {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

We could also use `requestAnimationFrame`:

```js
var test = document.querySelector('div#test');

var limit = 5;
var counter = 0;

const count = () => {
    counter++;
    test.textContent = counter;
    console.log(counter);
    alert('waiting …');
    counter<limit && requestAnimationFrame(count);
};
requestAnimationFrame(count)
```

```css
div#test {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: In your snippet, I don’t see any DOM changes until at the end.

Comment: Shouldn’t the `setTimeout` have a second argument?

Comment: @Manngo works fine in the chrome, check the answer (GIF), updated. the second argument is `0` by default

Comment: Works in Safari, too. If I change the delay, it also works in Firefox.

Comment: @Manngo hmm, firefox often does things in non-standard ways, let me test...

Comment: @Manngo i guess that's kinda a bug in FF, sh*t happens...

Comment: @Manngo added 10ms delay

Comment: OK, that solves the question. I now need to work out how to fit that in my real code. Thanks.

Comment: @Manngo `requestAnimationFrame` works in all browsers, added to the answer